# Get changed attributes on after_update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to make a conditional after_update, I have the following:

```
  after_update do |participant|
    Rails.logger.info "#{self.previous_changes} changed."
    if self.previous_changes.include?(:current_distance)
      #Do my stuff ...
    end
  end
```

The logger prints empty hash: `{}`

How can I check which attribute has been changed?

I am using: `participant.update_attribute(:current_distance, distance)` to update the attribute.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use `changes` not `previous_changes`. You are still in the same save transaction so what you are looking for is in `changes`. The `previous_changes` won't have the information until after the update completes.

**RAILS 5.1.1:**
use `saved_changes` instead of `changes` as it will be deprecated in new versions.

Comment: Cool stuff! But shouldn't the update be completed already when it reaches `after_update` callback?

Comment: No the update is not considered "complete" until the full callback chain is done. Please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for details.